# AttributeError: _auto_id_field Django with MongoDB and MongoEngine

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with Django
Below is my Model class

`class MyLocation(EmbeddedDocument):
    my_id = IntField(required=True)
    lat = GeoPointField(required=False)
    updated_date_time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)`

My Views.py

`def store_my_location():
    loc = MyLocation(1, [30.8993487, -74.0145665])
    loc.save()`

When I am calling the above method I getting error **AttributeError: _auto_id_field**

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the names when you save the location. Since class definition does not include how you put in these keys that is why we need to use the name to define them.

```
def store_my_location():
    loc = MyLocation(my_id=1, lat=[30.8993487, -74.0145665])
    loc.save()
```

This should work.

One more appraoch is to write everything in `MyLocation` class.

```
class MyLocation(EmbeddedDocument):
    my_id = IntField(required=True)
    lat = GeoPointField(required=False)
    updated_date_time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    def create(my_id,lat):
      location=MyLocation(my_id=my_id,lat=lat)
      location.save()
      return location

def store_my_location():
    loc = MyLocation.create(1,[30.8993487, -74.0145665])
```